# Publish and subscribe multi topics on the same node through different machines

Tags: ros, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
This is a common topic and I know some resources talking about it. I just want to know some additional information.
This is for ROS communication across multiple machines.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

They mention in session 4, to establish the communication in the other direction we need to kill the talker and listener, then bring them up on opposite machines.
Does it mean one machine can be only either talker and a listener at the time? Can we do both direct at the same time?
This is a video about one node publish and subscribe simultaneously.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR3cK9ZoAF8

If I implement it like that can I use the multiple machines method? In this case, I do not need to think which machine is a listener and which machine is a talker anymore right?
My application is a Simulator that connects with autonomous software and I use ROS1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376216/publish-and-subscribe-multi-topics-on-the-same-node-through-different-machines/) by [sgttrieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/73113/sgttrieu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> They mention in session 4, to establish the communication in the other direction we need to kill the talker and listener,

It's just an example to show that you can launch the nodes on any machine, there is no relation to a machine being "talker" or "listener".

A machine being "talker" just means that it publishes to topic(s) and "listener" just means it subscribes to topic(s). Any ros node can be subscriber (listener) and publisher (talker) at the same time, either susbcribing and publishing to the same or different topics.

The relevant thing in the tutorial you mention is to properly set `ROS_MASTER_URI` on the different machines to allow communication accross multiple machines.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgttrieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/73113/sgttrieu/) on 2021-04-22**:
I got it thanks